# TreeSet with comparable sorted by recursive dependency

Tags: java, comparable

I have a set of objects which have a name (a) and dependecies (b). I want to order the objects in a way where all previous dependecies are resolved. So I have this code:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Foo {
    static class TestOrder implements Comparable<TestOrder> {
        private final String a;
        private final Set<String> b;

        public TestOrder(String a, Set<String> b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
          }

        public int compareTo(TestOrder o) {
            if (o.b.contains(a)) 
              return -1;
            else
              return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return a.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return a.equals(obj);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return a + " - " + b.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<TestOrder> tos = new TreeSet<>();
        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("a", new HashSet<String>() {{
            add("b");
            add("c");
        }}));

        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("e", new HashSet<String>() {{
            add("a");
        }}));

        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("b", new HashSet<String>() {{
            add("d");
            add("c");
        }}));

        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("c", new HashSet<String>() {{ }}));
        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("d", new HashSet<String>() {{ }}));

        for (TestOrder to : tos) {
            System.out.println(to.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

which results in:

```
c - []
b - [d, c]
a - [b, c]
e - [a]
d - []
```

but - since b depends on d - the expected result would be:

```
c - []
d - []
b - [d, c]
a - [b, c]
e - [a]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing several things (in the harder-to-fix order, starting with the easier ones):

1. Your comparator never returns zero, even if the same object is passed to it,
2. When neither object depends on the other one, there is no definitive tie-breaker,
3. At the time of object insertion in the tree set, not all items are available; however, insertion of a single new item may change relative ordering of other items.
4. The ordering considers only immediate dependencies.

You can fix the first two relatively easily by checking the dependency of `this` on `o` before returning `1`, and using `a.compareTo(o.a)` for tie-breaking.

```
public int compareTo(TestOrder o) {
    if (o.b.contains(a)) 
      return -1;
    else if (b.contains(o.a))
      return 1;
    else
      return a.compareTo(o.a);
}
```

The third one could be fixed by switching to an array, and sorting it only after all the insertions have been made.

The last one, however, is very bad: in order to fix it, each item needs to know about the rest of the collection. I do not see a good way out of this, so I suggest using a traditional [*topological sorting algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to order your dependencies, rather than trying to shoehorn that problem in the framework of Java collections.

Answer (score 0):

Your compare method does not differ between an empty Set and a Set that does not contain the String "a". This compare method

```
    public int compareTo(TestOrder o) {
        if (o.b.contains(a)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            if (o.b.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty()) {
                return a.compareTo(o.a);
            } else
            if (o.b.isEmpty() || b.isEmpty()) {
                return b.isEmpty() ? -1 : 1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

will give the result

```
c - []
d - []
b - [d, c]
a - [b, c]
e - [a]
```

Comment: @KIC This does not solve the problem, only makes it a tiny bit harder to find. Add these dependencies in this order to see why: `a-[b]`, `c-[d]`, `b-[c]`, `d-[]`. It should produce `d-[], c-[d], b-[c], a-[b]`, yet a totally different output is produced ([link](http://ideone.com/WKsLJQ)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes you are right ... in the end I had to implement a simple topological sorting algorithm ... sorry Michael Besteck I had to change the correct Answer Tag ...

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, this is how it works - finally (thanks to dasblinkenlight):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Krusty
 */
public class Foo {
    static class TestOrder implements Comparable<TestOrder> {
        private final String a;
        private final Set<String> b;

        public TestOrder(String a, Set<String> b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
          }

        public int compareTo(TestOrder o) {
            if (o.b.contains(a)) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                if (o.b.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty()) {
                    return a.compareTo(o.a);
                } else
                if (o.b.isEmpty() || b.isEmpty()) {
                    return b.isEmpty() ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return a.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return a.equals(obj);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return a + " - " + b.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<TestOrder> tos = new TreeSet<>();
        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("a", new HashSet<String>() {{
            add("b");
            add("c");
        }}));

        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("e", new HashSet<String>() {{
            add("a");
        }}));

        // Cycle
        /*
        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("a", new HashSet<String>() {{
            add("e");
        }}));
        */
        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("b", new HashSet<String>() {{
            add("d");
            add("c");
        }}));

        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("c", new HashSet<String>() {{ }}));
        tos.add(new Foo.TestOrder("d", new HashSet<String>() {{ }}));

        /*
        for (TestOrder to : tos) {
            System.out.println(to.toString());
        }*/

        for (TestOrder to : sort(tos)) {
            System.out.println(to.toString());
        }
    }

    public static Set<TestOrder> sort(Set<TestOrder> tos) {
        Set<TestOrder> sorted = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Set<String> cache = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Set<TestOrder> cycles = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Set<String> cycache = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        Iterator<TestOrder> it;
        while ((it = tos.iterator()).hasNext()) {
            TestOrder to = it.next();
            if (to.b.isEmpty())  {
                sorted.add(to);
                cache.add(to.a);
                it.remove();
            } else if (cache.containsAll(to.b)) {
                sorted.add(to);
                cache.add(to.a);
                it.remove();
            } else if (cycache.containsAll(to.b)) {
                cycles.add(to);
                cycache.add(to.a);
                it.remove();
            } else {
                cycles.add(to);
                cycache.add(to.a);
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        System.err.println("cycles");
        for (TestOrder to : cycles) {
            System.err.println(to.toString());
        }

        return sorted;
    }
}
```